# I want to change let's say the values of [a b c d e] within a text which has repeated occurrences of these letters with values [f h d o t] all at once

Tags: string, matlab, text

I can easily replace each every letter by doing them one after another but when i use loop it won't.

```
a = strrep(a,'b','z');
a = strrep(a,'a','e');
a = strrep(a,'c','f'); 
but for i = 1:size(a,2)
a = strrep(a,'b','z');
a = strrep(a,'a','e');
a = strrep(a,'c','f');
```

end
only change 'b' and 'a' not all. so lets say if we str 'abcdabc' then replace one after another gives right answer but loop shows the result as 'ezedeze'. so please help with this.

Comment: Ha ...sure ...  posted in this way, the question is more clear ... :)

Comment: Did you see that nothing in your code depends on the loop variable `i`? This already hints that there are severe problems in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches:

1. With [`changem`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/changem.html) (from the Mapping Toolbox):

   ```
   str = 'basic example string';
   old = 'abcde';
   new = 'fhdot';
   str = changem(str, new, old);
   ```
2. With [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

   ```
   str = 'basic example string';
   old = 'abcde';
   new = 'fhdot';
   [ind1, ind2] = ismember(str, old);
   new = 'fhdot';
   str(ind1) = new(ind2(ind1));
   ```

Comment: Note: `changem` only exists if you have Mapping toolbox but a great approach.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the tip, I've edited my answer. It's my first-time use of `changem`, after I saw it in an answer by Divakar the other day. I hadn't even noticed it was in a toolbox :-)